# Работа с xlm темами в drawable

Tags: android, resources

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. В программе создал 2 кнопки ImageButton. Для них создал фон в XML.

Тут я указал два состояния кнопки, нажатое и обычное

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/oval_start_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/oval_start"/>
</selector>
```

Вот использованные выше в коде xml файлы состояний:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorStart"/>
            <size android:height="@dimen/button_oval" android:width="@dimen/button_oval"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

и для нажатого состояния

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorStartPressed"/>
            <size android:height="@dimen/button_oval" android:width="@dimen/button_oval"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

В коде я используя метод `mImageButtonAction.setImageResource(R.mipmap.file_name);` установил нужные мне картинки на кнопки. А какой код надо использовать чтобы установить XML файл с описанными состояниями кнопки? Что-то типа `mImageButtonAction.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.states_button_start);` так не работает конечно))

И еще такой момент. У кнопок 4 разных назначения. То есть если я нажал на кнопку Старт с примененным стилем states_button_start.xml, мне после нажатия надо системно установить другую картинку на кнопке (это я умею) и применить другой стиль (по этому вопросу и создал тему). И так у меня получилось очень много XML файлов. Один файл в котором описаны два состояния кнопки и два файла для каждого состояния. И умножить на 4 разных варианта кнопки (старт, пауза, стоп, сброс). Итого 12 файлов. Может возможно (и правильнее) несколько файлов соединить в один и там сразу описать разные стили и т.д. Я просто не знаю как, в гугле пока ответов не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Сори. Не могу добавить комментарий. Думаю вот эта статья ответит на ваши вопросы по поводу рефакторинга. http://habrahabr.ru/post/206064/

Comment: Рекомендую вынести из статьи основные моменты в ответ а ссылку оставить как дополнение в качестве подробностей. В этом случае ценность вашего ответа не сильно уменьшится, если ссылка станет битой (а это бывает даже с ссылками на хабр)

Answer (score 0):

На первый вопрос нашел ответ, просто посмотрел какие варианты предлагает Android Studio. Нужным методом является `mImageButtonReset.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_file);`

Еще нашел способ как писать все более сжато. Вместо трех файлов, которые я показал в вопросе можно создать всего один с таким кодом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- сточкой android:state_pressed="true" указываем что это нажатое состояние -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorStartPressed"/>
            <size android:height="@dimen/button_oval" android:width="@dimen/button_oval"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorStart"/>
            <size android:height="@dimen/button_oval" android:width="@dimen/button_oval"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```